# Problem of finding General value

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

The general value $e^i$ is given by___

$$e^i=e^{\cos(2n\pi+\pi/2)+i\sin(2n\pi+\pi/2)}=e^{e^{2n\pi+\pi/2}}, \quad \forall n\in I$$

Is it right? But here, I need answer $e^{-(2n\pi+\pi/2)}, \forall n\in I$

How to get that answer?

Comment: I think its $i^i=e^{i\text{Log }i}=e^{i*(2n\pi+ \frac{\pi}2)}=e^{-(2n\pi+\frac\pi2)}$

Comment: General value of $log i=(2n\pi+\pi/2)$?

Comment: $i=\cos(2n\pi+\frac\pi2)+i\sin(2n\pi+\frac\pi2)=e^{i(2n\pi+\frac\pi2)}$ apply log

Comment: Ok Ok $e^{i*i(2n\pi+\pi/2)}$. Ok. But for the above problem, Is my answer right?$e^{e^{2n\pi+\pi/2}}$,

Comment: No, its $$e^{e^{i(2n\pi+\frac\pi2)}}$$

Comment: Sorry, You are right. Thank you. May be there is a mistake in problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9130/discussion-between-shree6174-and-lab-bhattacharjee)